# Bash sort and multi-character tab error

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have data in the following form

```
C1510438;;C0220832;;2
C0026030;;C0034693;;1
C1257960;;C0007452;;1
C0061461;;C0027922;;2
C0011744;;C0037494;;3
C0014180;;C0034493;;3
```

When I try to sort on the 3rd field, the command returns the error

```
sort -t ';;' -k 3 -r -n -o output.txt input.txt
sort: multi-character tab `;;'
```

I also try with

```
sort -t $';;' -k 3 -r -n -o output.txt input.txt
```

but the command returns same error.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-t` option expects a single separator character, but you give it two. A way to do what you want would be to consider that the separator is only a single `;`, and thus the third column would become the fifth one:

```
sort -t ';' -k 5 -r -n -o output.txt input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the -t option expects a single separator character, a good way to handle this would be to use a replace tool to temporarily replace the separator(s) with a new one, do the sort, and then restore the original separator(s) as needed for further processing.  I have a file that uses "," as separator which I can temporarily replace with a | (pipe), do my sort, and then restore "," as separator.